# Max file size to upload in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, max-size

I am stuck with file uploading.
I set 500M in PHP, but still there is a limit of 5M.
It is limited by `$this->max_size` (library upload.php).
I don't get it. How can it be set?

Comment: make an .user.ini file in your root directory and put upload_max_filesize = 128M
post_max_size = 10M there

Answer (score 3):

There are three different places where you have to update:

1) php.ini

2) .htaccess

3) in your file where you want update max_upload_size

In php.ini file, you have to update this:

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '200M');  
ini_set('post_max_size', '200M');
```

In .htaccess, you have update below:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 128M  
php_value post_max_size 128M
```

And last in your file, you have to add this line:

```
$config['max_size'] = '1000000';
```